# `flask db migrate` error

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

We are trying to run a `flask db migrate` and `flask db upgrade` which throws the following error:

> ```
> Usage: flask db upgrade [OPTIONS] [REVISION]
>
> Error: The file/path provided (C) does not appear to exist.  Please verify the path 
>            is correct.  If app is not on PYTHONPATH, ensure the extension is .py
> ```

We have added the app's directory to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable but still get the error. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is our `__init__.py` code. Are we missing something?

```
import logging
from flask import Flask
from flask_appbuilder import SQLA, AppBuilder

"""
 Logging configuration
"""

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s')
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLA(app)
appbuilder = AppBuilder(app, db.session)
migrate.init_app(app, db)


"""
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlalchemy import event

#Only include this for SQLLite constraints
@event.listens_for(Engine, "connect")
def set_sqlite_pragma(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    # Will force sqllite contraint foreign keys
    cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON")
    cursor.close()
"""    

from app import views
```

Comment: Are you in the flask app directory when you run the command? Have you configured your app to use `migrate` as shown here - https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.    
 `app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///app.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)`

Comment: We are in the correct directory however we may not have configured the app correctly. The code you refer to needs to be added to `__init__.py` correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think if you are using migrate like you are

```
migrate.init_app(app, db)
```

that you first have to import it and then declare it:

```
from flask_migrate import Migrate
migrate = Migrate()
migrate.init_app(app, db)
```

or alternatively I think you could do:

```
from flask_migrate import Migrate
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
```