# How to migrate data from sqllite to mysql in flask-appbuilder

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-appbuilder

I am new to flask but i have experience in Django. I have a under development project and this project is using **SQLLITE** for storing and accessing data. 
Whenever we run the application it create table and store data in the **SQLLITE** table for the first time.

Now, We want to migrate this data into MYSQL and I have updated the **SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI** in **config.py** and when i am trying to run this application after above update, nothing is happening.

Can anyone assist me with this. How do we setup MYSQL database with flask-appbuilder. Do we need to manually create all the tables in database?

Comment: not sure that using `Flask` tools for such kind of operations is a good way. look at [liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to run migrations again:

```
flask db init
flask db migrate -m "all_tables"
flask db upgrade
```

Then you have to migrate data to mysql

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have figure it out. This project is using SQLA package for DB connections and SQL queries. And the connection string i was using was not working. So I've looked into official site of SQLA and found that connection string should be **SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://user:password@localhost/DBNAME'.** So after adding pymysql package everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to import `flask_migrate` module in the `app/__init__.py`.

Sample:

```py
...
# default imports by appbuilder
...
from flask_migrate import Migrate


app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLA(app
migrate = Migrate()
migrate.init_app(app, db)
appbuilder = AppBuilder(app, db.session)
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52075985/664229

And then, please run as suggested by [Edmhs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403411/edmhs)!